# How to use "!" as the comment indicator, but also NOT operator in language syntax highlight?

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, tmlanguage

I am using VScode and create my own language extension to highlight syntax, where I need to use regular expression to find the comments.

The basic rule is that everything after `!` is a comment, however there is a special case. When `!` is inside `eval()` command, it means NOT.

For example some of my code would look like:

```
if condition=(eval(!DB_EXIST)) ! this is a comment
(eval( !DB_UPDATED && !DB_EXIST)) !---"!" inside eval() means NOT
!this is another comment
<some commands> ! this is also a comment
```

The `!DB_EXIST` in line 1 and 2 should not be interpreted as comments, and `!` will be followed by a non-space.

Whitespace doesn't matter in comments.

```
"comments": {
    "patterns" [{
        "match":"regex1",
        "name":"comment"
    }]
},
"operator": {
    "patterns" [{
        "match":"regex2",
        "name":"keyword.operator.NOT"
    }]
},
```

What kind of regex 1 and 2 should I use to show different color for comments and NOT?

I am not good at this extension writing, so if there is any better way to do the job I will be very appreciated to hear.
Thanks!

**Update**

@Gama11 helped me but I didn't completely cover all the case in my code samples.
Any non-sapce after "!" should also be comments, as long as "!" is not inside eval().

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```json
{
    "$schema": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Septh/tmlanguage/master/tmLanguage.schema.json",
    "scopeName": "source.abc",
    "patterns": [
        {
            "begin": "(eval)\\(",
            "end": "\\)",
            "captures": {
                "1": {
                    "name": "entity.name.function"
                }
            },
            "patterns": [
                {
                    "include": "#parens"
                },
                {
                    "match": "!",
                    "name": "keyword"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "match": "!.*?$",
            "name": "comment"
        }
    ],
    "repository": {
        "parens": {
            "begin": "\\(",
            "end": "\\)",
            "patterns": [
                {
                    "include": "#parens"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

We put the pattern for the non-comment `!` first, since it's more specific and should have priority over the other one. Also, I used the `"keyword"` scope instead of the more appropriate `"keyword.operator.NOT"` so it actually shows a different color in the screenshot.

The first regex is a `begin`-`end` pattern, which allows us to apply patterns only for the text between those two matches (in this case within an `eval()` calll). While we're at it, we might as well highlight `eval` as a function with the `entity.name.function` scope.

If we're within a `eval()`, we allow two patterns:

- a recursive `begin`-`end` pattern (includes itself) to balance the parentheses (you could presumably have something like `eval(foo() + !bar())`, and the `)` in `foo()` shouldn't end the `eval`-pattern)
- the `!` operator we're interested in in the first place

The second regex simply matches `!`, and then anything (`.*?`) until the end of the line (`$`).

In general, I'd highly recommend using a tool like [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/) for playing around with the regexes of TM Grammar files. Much easier than iterating in VSCode itself since you get instant feedback.

Comment: Wow, I think this is exactly what I want! You are amazing! I learned a lot from it, especially this recursive pattern. It is really useful. Thanks!